Why Does Firebase Android Authentication Throw `Developer_Error`?
I have a react native app and try to get my Firebase authentication to run. On Web and iOS everything works fine, but on Android I get a Developer_Error and nothing else
I had to delete my first Android App with SHA1 and 256 Key in Firebase and create a new one (with the same keys... didn't find a way to generate new ones on android/google). Is this part of the problem?
The SHA1 and 256 Keys are correct, the bundle id is correct. What am I missing?
Merry Christmas to everyone, and thanks for your help.

Please make sure your sha keys are correctly configured in google cloud console. Refer these urls below.
firebase-statuscode-developer-error
google-signin/issues/1192

GoogleSignin.configure({
   webClientId:''
 });

Make sure you have a valid WebclientId.
For this you need to goto:
1)Firebase Console first.
2)Navigate to Authentication.
3)Press on Sign-in method.
4)Look for sign-in provider make sure you have enabled the google Signin(if not enabled it).
5)Press on google swipe down you will see Web Sdk configuration press on it thats your Web Client ID.
6)Make Sure you have SHA-1 fingerprint pasted in you your android App bundle inside project settings.
7)if not then configure your SHA-1 fingerprint(https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) go to project-overview section look for your android app press on it paste it there in the SHA-1 SECTION.
8)after configuring your SHA-1 fingerprint update your google-services.Json
9)go to your root folder then cd/android
10)type
./gradlew clean
11)build your app again it takes 4 to 24 hours for firebase after SHA-1 configuration so be patient.
